# libGDX Box2DDebugRenderer Draw Box Too Big & Too Small

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

So, I just want to draw `Box2DDebugRenderer` same with sprite size.
I have use same `SpriteBatch` same `Camera` and same `Viewport`. It took me 8 hours, tried finding a solution around google and still not solve the problem.

Here what I got:
[image: 32x32]
[image: 16x16]

I just change this line:

```
PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
shape.setAsBox(32, 32);
```

Some tutorial said to div by 2. I tried that I got result like 2nd picture.

Here my script

`PlayScreen.java`:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private TiledMap tileMap;
    private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Player player;
    private World world;
    private Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
    private FitViewport gamePort;

    public PlayScreen(HookaHookaGame game) {
        this.batch = game.getSpriteBatch();
        this.world = new World(new Vector2(0, -20), true);

        // Create cam
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        gamePort = new FitViewport(800, 600, cam);
        gamePort.apply(true);

        //initially set our gamcam to be centered correctly at the start of of map
        // cam.position.set(400, 300, 0);
        // cam.update();

        // Load tilemap
        tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("simulation01.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap, batch);

        // Create box2d debug renderer
        debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

        // Create player sprite
        player = new Player(this.world);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        //cam.update();

        // Update sprite
        player.update(delta);

        //Clear the game screen with Black
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw tilemap
        tiledMapRenderer.setView(cam);
        tiledMapRenderer.render();

        // Set camera to spritebatch
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        // Draw sprite
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(player.getKeyFrame(), 300, 300);
        player.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        // Draw box2d debug renderer
        debugRenderer.render(world, cam.combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

`Player.java`, extended from Sprite Class:

```
public class Player extends Sprite {
    private Animation anim;
    private float stateTimer;
    private World world;
    private Body body;

    // Debug
    public Player(World world) {
        stateTimer = 0;
        this.world = world;

        loadAnim();
    }

    private void loadAnim() {
        Array<TextureRegion> temp = new Array<TextureRegion>(40);

        Texture texture = new Texture("sprite.png");
        temp.add(new TextureRegion(texture, 3*32, 3*32, 32, 32));
        temp.add(new TextureRegion(texture, 2*32, 3*32, 32, 32));
        temp.add(new TextureRegion(texture, 32, 3 * 32, 32, 32));
        temp.add(new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 3*32, 32, 32));

        anim = new Animation(0.1f, temp, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.position.set(100, 100);
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(32, 32);

        FixtureDef fixture = new FixtureDef();
        fixture.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fixture);

        setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32);
        setPosition(100, 100);
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        stateTimer += delta;

        setRegion(getKeyFrame());
        setSize(32, 32);
    }

    public TextureRegion getKeyFrame() {
        return anim.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
    }
}
```

Could you explain what happen exactly?

Comment: you also need to scale down the world because box2d world works in meters and texture are drawn in pixels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Box2d and Textures have different origins.

The origin of the body is its center.

The origin of the Texture is the bottom left corner.

[image]

As you can see, the center of the box2d object is exactly at the bottom left corner of the texture, if you draw them both at the same position.

Pseudo code:

```
batch.draw(texture, body.x - texture.width / 2, body.y - texture.heigth / 2);
```

Otherwise you could set the origin of the box2d body to "the bottom left corner", but that might give you trouble if you follow other tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

you can also put the origin of your sprite to center by calling the function **setOriginCenter()** of your Sprites before drawing them

so the spritebatch will draw them from center just like your box